# How can I trigger this SQL query the right way?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my problem:

> Create a trigger which will add the id and age columns of rows deleted
>   from the table "metadata" to the "metadata2" table.

The query that will be run to check if the trigger works is:
`DELETE FROM metadata WHERE ID=40124197; SELECT * FROM metadata2`.

So, what did I do? I did this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER somerandomtrigger
AFTER INSERT ON metadata2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO metadata2 (id, age)
END
```

Yet it keeps saying: `Query failed: near "END": syntax error`, but I don't get why.

Comment: where is the `values` clause of the `insert` statement?

Comment: Do you not need semi-colons on lines 5 and 6?

Comment: Why are you using an `AFTER INSERT`, you describe an `AFTER DELETE` trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you used the wrong event trigger on the worng table.

When you delete a record from metadata table, you want to insert some data from this record into metadata2.

On delete trigger, there is a a records managed by MySQL named OLD containing the record that has been deleted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER somerandomtrigger
AFTER DELETE ON metadata
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO metadata2(id, age) VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.age);
END;
```

[Syntax and examples of MySQL trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Hi, it still gives me an error. Now, it says: Query failed: near ".": syntax error

Comment: @Siyah I assumed the code was valid. I updated my answer.